# How to i fade an image into another image for when they transition photo slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im new to javascript and was making a photo slideshow.I was wondering how do i make it fade and another photo shows up instead of what i have is photos blinking into transition.Thank you

```
      var myImage = document.getElementById("banner");
       var ArrayImage = 
      ["front/slider1.jpg","front/slider3.jpg","front/slider2.jpg"];
      var imageIdex = 0;

      function changeImage(){
      myImage.setAttribute("src", ArrayImage[imageIdex]);
      imageIdex++;

        if (imageIdex >= ArrayImage.length) {
            imageIdex = 0;
        }
           }

       setInterval(changeImage,2000);
```

Comment: Use css to overlay the new image with a higher z-index. have opacity at 0 initially, then either use css transition to change that to 1 or jquery fadeIn() to do it with js. what you're doing now is changing the src with an unloaded image. it will blink for sure

Comment: okay thank you i will try